# Remote HTTP Endpoint to Docker Application

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a demo application running perfectly on my local environment. However, I would like to run the same application remotely by giving it a HTTP endpoint. My goal is to test the performance of the application.

How to give a HTTP endpoint to any multi container docker application?

The following is the Github repository link for the demo application

https://github.com/LonareAman/BankCQRS.git

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker-compose` and handle containers based on what you need

One of your containers should be `web server` like `nginx`. And then bind your machine port to your `nginx` like `80:80`

Then handle your containers in `nginx` and make a proxy to them

You can find some samples in https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/